# Alternative read file method

Tags: java, arrays, file, store

I am having trouble storing values from a file.

```
3
10 2
100 35
5 4
17 20 3 5
6 10
6 9 12 15 18 21 24 27 30 33
```

I wish to store the first line as an integer and the other lines with multiple values as separate int arrays.

```
    BufferedReader br = null;
    try {
        String sCurrentLine;
        br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("candy.dat"));
        while ((sCurrentLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(sCurrentLine);
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            if (br != null)br.close();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Is there another way to do so? Thanks

EDIT: Basically the first integer (in this example is 3) will represent how many test cases there are to follow. Each test case will be followed by two lines. So the first test case is [10, 2] [100, 35].

EDIT2: I managed to fix my problem if anyone was wondering.
this is my code

```
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(new File("candy.dat"));
    String testCase = sc.nextLine();
    String[] numOfCandy = new String[0];
    String[] NK = new String[0];

    for (int i = 0; i < Integer.parseInt(testCase); i++) {
        System.out.println("test case " + (i+1));
        NK = sc.nextLine().split(" ");
        numOfCandy = sc.nextLine().split(" ");

        //System.out.println(NK[0] + " " + NK[1]);
        //System.out.println(numOfCandy[0] + " " + numOfCandy[1]);

        find(NK[0], NK[1], numOfCandy); //method to solve problem
    }
```

I first stored the testcase value, which is 3, to tell the for loop how many times to run.

I instantiated 2 String arrays for later use.

Inside the for loop, I read the next line and split it to store into string array NK, and then the line after that to store into numOfCandy.

From there, I was able to successfully retrieve data from the arrays to solve my problem.

Comment: Your question is not very clear.  You have working code to a point, but it seems you have not tried to go any further with the solution.  What bit are you actually stuck on?

Comment: if I were in your shoes, I'd store this data in some well-defined structure and persist/retrieve as a JSON string. 2c.

Answer (score 0):

Answer, now, no time, no brain... Pretty cool attitude: `

```
public static void main() throws Exception {
    final Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File(file_str));
    while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
        if (scanner.hasNextInt()) {
            final int nb = scanner.nextInt();
            System.err.println(nb);
            final String[] str = scanner.findInLine(".*").split(" ");
            System.err.println("-----" + str);
        }

    }
    System.err.println("END");
    scanner.close();
}
```